# Is there a way to forcefully use a hidden default constructor in Julia?

Tags: julia

I want to serialize and deserialize Julia objects from an external package. Some of these objects only have restricted inner constructors, like in the following example:

```
module ExternalModule
  struct SillyType
    f::Float64
    function SillyType(i::Int)
      new(float(i))
    end
  end
end
```

To reconstruct objects/structs from the stored values (here, to reconstruct the `SillyType` using a float), I need to call the default constructor, which is not available:

```
julia> ExternalModule.SillyType(2.0)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Main.ExternalModule.SillyType(::Float64)
```

The [Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/) says

> If any inner constructor method is defined, no default constructor
>   method is provided: it is presumed that you have supplied yourself
>   with all the inner constructors you need.

Is there a way around this to somehow forcefully call the missing default constructor? And what would be the least dirty approach for this?

Comment: In this case, as this is the `struct` I think it is enough that just convert what you want to `Int` and call the constructor. If you had `mutable struct` the situation would be more tricky. Probably the best way would be to create a struct with arbitrary data and then set its fields to appropriate values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `new` function inside the inner constructor of `SillyType` is what you want to call? It is normally only allowed in inner constructors, but if you forge it using macros, it will still run. Try this:

```
julia> macro new(args...)
         return Expr(:new, args...)
       end
@new (macro with 1 method)

julia> @new(SillyType, 4.)
SillyType(4.0)
```